# Can't click on button after declaring z-index?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am unable to click on button after giving z-index to it. It's overlapping on my side navigation bar I don't know why, any suggestions would be great:) .
How can I make it clickable even after z-index=-1

MY CODE :

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-0 col-xs-4"  >
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id="lovehate" style="left:17px; top:20px;" ></span>
  <a href="{{route('lovebutton',['username' => $user->username,'action'=>'love']) }}" > 
  <button  class="btn btn-md  btn-default  btn-lg-round waves-effect waves-teal" type="button" style="z-index: -1; "  id="lovebtn">Love</button>    
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: without z index -1]
[image: with z index]

[image: how it looks]

Comment: When you give z-index = -1, your button must be hiding or going below another element, right?

Comment: can you show a fiddle

Comment: I think you have to give positive z-index or if navigation bar has z-index then you should give a value more than that

Comment: yes but after closing that element which hides the button . the button just shows me a simple cursor . i mean it's not clickable

Comment: we can understand the question, but not understand the situation

Comment: provide more code is very usefull

Comment: if i do give z-index to my button it pops up from my nav bar

Comment: ok wait i will make a fiddle

Comment: It's good to show us in a fiddle

Comment: my code is 2000 lines + i was unable to make js fiddle  i could get these images if you can suggest anything . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for those element that `z-index` value has not assigned, it's `z-index` value is auto. and for as long as you do not post more of your code we are not going to be able to help.

I tried your code you provided here: https://jsfiddle.net/cb16h3jo/ and the button is responsive.

You can inspect you button in your browser and see if any other element is overlaying in your element. If so then change that element `z-index` to something lower than your button `z-indez` says: `z-index: -2`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a reason for setting the zindex to -1? is not that your button is not clickable, is that probably something is overlapping it (I've tried the piece of code you posted and I can click on the button).

Answer (score 1):

you could use high values to bring the button to top layer... try

```
z-index=3
```

or
    z-index=5 
or
    z-index=9